# Why is the Hogwarts crest / coat of arms plus motto canon?

Tags: harry-potter, canon, hogwarts

Specifically: why does everyone refer to the art that is reproduced at the beginning of most HP editions (complete with motto) as *the* actual crest of Hogwarts and not just like any other piece of cover or inside art.

I know that JKR has said in some interviews that Draco dormiens nunquam titillandus is the school motto and (if I remember well) that there is a broad-strokes description of the coat of arms in Goblet of Fire.

(I'm sorry if this is a loaded question and it isn't canon after all.)

Comment: FWIW JKR has hand-drawn the crest in her "personal copy" full of handwritten notations that was IIRC auctioned for charity http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2013/05/18/article-0-19D9E7C4000005DC-608_634x938.jpg. While it may be that she simply copied the existing one (as opposed to having created it herself) it could suggest that she *now* considers it canon regardless. Here it can be seen that the first edition DID NOT have the crest

Comment: IIRC the crest is based on a sketch from JKR

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The crest has been seen on the inside cover of various editions of Harry Potter and the Philosopher's stone.

[image]

For added "canon" weight, there's a signed copy available [here](http://www.rareandsigned.com/?page=shop/flypage&product_id=168728) for just £4950

[image]

JKR also hand-drew her own version of the crest in a volume that she later [auctioned for charity](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/entertainment-arts-22622194). It fetched £150,000 if you happen to be looking for an investment

[image]

Interestingly, the very first instance of the motto seems to be on the Official Harry Potter Fan Club certificates. I've been unable to find a scanned copy of one, but there's a mention [here](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/1998/0798-telegraph-bertodano.html) in a Telegraph interview from 1997.

and in the [interview below,](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2000/0700-bloomsbury-fry.html) she discusses why she chose it.

> **SF:** *And names like that. Even the school crest is something which is rather fun for those of us who have done a bit of Latin. For
>   instance: “Draco dormiens nunquam titillandus” – it’s sort of like
>   “Let sleeping dogs lie”, but it is “Don’t tickle a sleeping dragon”.*
>
> **JKR:** *“Don’t tickle a sleeping dragon”, exactly.*
>
> **SF:** *Which is fine advice.*
>
> **JKR:** *I wanted good practical advice. All the schools I’ve ever been to or taught in have mottos: “Persevere”, “Onwards and Upwards”.
>   I wanted good solid practical advice for Hogwarts*